# How to handle Spring Data JPA deletes when deleting by PK that does not exist?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**What is the best way to handle errors when using Spring's Jpa Repository `deleteById(Long id)` method?**

By default the `deleteById()`, checks to see if the ID has an existing row in the database, if it doesn't it throws a `org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException` because it expects a row size of 1.

I first tried to use my Exception Handler to pick up on this exception, which worked fine but the message exposes my package and class name to the user when Spring returns the error message.

```
@ExceptionHandler(EmptyResultDataAccessException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
protected ResponseEntity<RestApiError> handleEmptyResultDataAccessException(EmptyResultDataAccessException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
    RestApiError error = new RestApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, Map.of("message", ex.getMessage()), request.getRequestURI());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(error, error.getHttpStatus());
}
```

`ex.getMessage()` returns:

> No class net.demo.customerservice.model.CustomerLocation
> entity with id 7 exists!

Instead I decided to catch `EmptyResultDataAccessException`, and then throw more useful exception and message where I call `deleteById()`;

My current code:

```java
public void delete(Long id) {
  try {
     repository.deleteById(id); // call Spring's Data JPA repository method deleteById
  } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
     throw new EntityNotFoundException("Location with ID: [" + id + "] was not found");
  }
}
```

This works great, and returns a good error message to the user but it seems like a hack.

Is there any better way to handle the `EmptyResultDataAccessException`? I could also use the `existsById()` method before calling the delete method, but then I am using **two** queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it's better to avoid catching exceptions throughout the code. If you can delegate exception handling to another class, you can handle errors consistently across your application in one place. You could use `@ControllerAdvice` for this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(EmptyResultDataAccessException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<> handleRecordNotFound(EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
        LOG.trace("Record not found: {}", ex.getMessage());
        RestApiError error = new RestApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, Map.of("message", "Record not found"), request.getRequestURI());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, error.getHttpStatus());
    }
}
```

The client knows which entity it requested to delete, so there's no need to include the id in the error message returned to the client. You could log the message with he id to the log file.

Comment: That is a fair point especially since in my error details I pass back the path, and the endpoint's path uses the ID that the user wants deleted. i.e `/customer/location/2`